# How can I edit my MySQL DB from any computer?

Tags: python, mysql

I created a Python program that accesses a MySQL DB.  What it does when it runs is it edits the Logged_in column of the user to 1, so I know this user logged in.

```
UPDATE users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = "username";
```

Works perfect. Every time it runs, it edits the DB so I know who logged on.

Problem is, it works only on my computer. When someone else uses it, it says

```
DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can´t connect to MySQL server on 'ip address'
```

I do not understand what I have to do to make this DB accessible and editable from anywhere and anyone.

I appreciate any advice.

NOTE: I read similar problems, a solution is making a the computer that wants to access a host, but I need this DB to be editable literally by anyone running the program, so I won't have their computer's information.

Simplified code:

```py
import mysql.connector

#User inputs username and password in Tkinter GUI
username = "StackOverflow"
password = "123456"

def main():
        
    #ACCESS DB
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="my_computer_ip",
        user="database_user",
        password="password",
        database = "users",
        port=3306
        )
    
    #GET CURSOR (ALLOW TO EXECUTE COMMANDS)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    
    #GET USER INFORMATION
    mycursor.execute("SELECT username, password, logged_in FROM users WHERE 
                      username = '{}';".format(username))
    
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
    
    #Display results if user is found.
    if myresult is not None and len(myresult) > 0:
        print("Connection Successful! \n User:{} \n Pass{}".format(myresult[0], myresult[1]))

    else:
        print("User does not exist.")
        return False
    
    # Next step is to match the input password to the one in the database,
    # If they match, allow access to the GUI.
    # Also, logged in column would be changed to 1 to let the database know the user is on.
    
main()
```

Comment: Could you provide you whole Python program (or at least some)?

Comment: *When someone else uses it* - another account on the same workstation? or an account in another OS instance?

Comment: As the error says, the ip address of the database server is not accessible to the other user. If the database in on your local machine you won't have problem.

Comment: AbhigyanJaiswal - Thank you for your reply. I added simplified code, hope it is ok!

Akina - I would use a user with the necessary privileges.  OS would be windows, like mine, but from a different machine. The user does not have Workbench installed, the changes are just to keep track of who uses the Python program.

jignatius - I want to make it accessible by other people from any other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your database user might be accessible through localhost only. Check the database users and privileges. If you are using MySQL Workbench, you can run this query:

***SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;***

The **Host** assigned to the database user should be a wildcard (%) and not *localhost* in order to access the database anywhere.

It's either you create another database user with a % host or you update the existing one.

***CREATE USER 'database_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';***
or
***UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='database_user';***

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The user has a % host.

The database runs from my machine. Workbench has a server tab and it says running so I guessed the databases would be accessible as long as my machine was turned on, am I wrong?